# String to DateTime conversion Failing

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datetime, type-conversion

I'm trying to convert a string from a text file to a DateTime, but I'm getting weird results. On one computer, it works, but another, it doesn't. How would I make this work on all computers? On my last question, you said to add the culture thing, and it worked for a few minutes, but it's not working again now. Heres my code:

```
string[] stringArray = File.ReadAllLines("C:\\Program Files\\PointOfSales\\RecordTotals.txt");
            int lines = stringArray.Length;

            for (int i = 0; i < (lines / 5); i++)
            {
                TransactionList.Add(new Transaction
                {
                    TotalEarned = Convert.ToDouble(stringArray[(i * 5)]),
                    TotalCost = Convert.ToDouble(stringArray[(i * 5) + 1]),
                    TotalHST = Convert.ToDouble(stringArray[(i * 5) + 2]),
                    Category = stringArray[(i * 5) + 3],
                    HoursSince2013 = Convert.ToDateTime(stringArray[(i * 5) + 4], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                });
            }
```

I'm getting the error `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.`

Any clues whats up? Thanks!

Edit: Using `MessageBox.Show(stringArray[(i * 5) + 4]);` I get `26/10/2013 11:58:03 AM`

Edit: Why won't this work to convert current time to the right culture?

```
DateTime Today = DateTime.Now;
            Today = DateTime.ParseExact(Today.ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: could you post the string that is failing?  Everything looks good from this end

Comment: Is the file always the same?

Comment: What is the value of `stringArray[(i * 5) + 4]` exactly when you debug your program?

Comment: Just posted the string, and the file will always be different, it's a database containing Transaction Records

Comment: IMO, the magic numbers and vague variable names make this code difficult to follow.  Please fix the naming and consider separating the data parsing from the `Transaction` object creation.  Maybe a real DB instead of a text file.

Comment: What is the format of your `DateTime.Now` date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string, on that system, is not a valid date in invariant culture: `26/10/2013 11:58:03 AM`. The invariant culture expects month/day/year, not day/month/year.

You should specify the same culture that is being used to generate the file that you are reading.  You will need to have some way to determine or standardize on the cultures being used for writing to the file, as well as reading from it.

---

> Edit: Why won't this work to convert current time to the right culture?

That will fail if your current culture doesn't use `dd/MM/yyyy` for it's format.  `Today.ToString()` doesn't have a culture specified, or a format, so it's going to, on  a US system, write out using `MM/dd/yyyy` format, which will cause the call to fail.

In your case, I would recommend always reading and writing using the same culture - If you write your file using:  `theDate.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`, then you can read using `Convert.ToDateTime(theString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`, and it *will work on any system*, since the same rules (Invariant culture) are used for both writing and reading.

Comment: So if I change my format of the date, this code will work on all computers?

Comment: @Nathan Yes - if you always write the dates using `InvariantCulture`, you could always read them the same way.

Comment: or simply try using `DateTime.TryParseExact`

Comment: @KingKing That's not really going to help - it'll break his first system, then ;)  The problem is he has 2 files with different date cultures in each, on different systems.  He has to standardize somehow.

Comment: @ReedCopsey you may be right, we still need to know the format which is used to write the file, it's for the case we can identify some expression like this `2/1/2013` (without format info, we don't know that is `the first February` or `the second January` although it always parses that expression OK.

Comment: I'm trying this to create the current DateTime in the correct format, but I get the same error as in the original post. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for the help by the way :)

Code in OP

Comment: @Nathan How are you *creating* the file?  If you're using `DateTime.ToString`, use `DateTime.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` instead - then your current code would work.

Comment: Edit: Durr I understand, let me try that

Comment: @Nathan it should work if you read and write in the same way, we don't need `ParseExact` or `TryParseExact` in this case.

Comment: Ahh, I understand now. I just have to modify my code to make everything work properly. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

You should use custom `"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss t"` format with [`InvariantCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture.aspx) like;

```
string s = "26/10/2013 11:58:03 AM";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(s, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(dt);
```

Output will be;

```
10/26/2013 11:58:03 AM
```

Here a <kbd>[`demonstration`](http://ideone.com/GAZ8zS)</kbd>.

For more information, take a look at;

- [`Custom Date and Time Format Strings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

**EDIT**: If your `DateTime.Now` doesn't fit `"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt"` format, your program will fail. You should use `InvariantCulture` in all your programs with your `DateTime.Now` format exactly.

Comment: Note that this will fix the broken system, but break the currently working system.

Comment: @ReedCopsey Yes of course, that's the reason why OP should use same culture all his systems..